# eclipse RCP build updatesite for multiple features

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, update-site

need your expertise on this..
Is it possible to build an update site for more than one feature?  (ex: two different features are updated via one update site)

Comment: Are you using PDE automated build, or simply exporting an update site from your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

It is easily possible to create an update site for multiple features. Just create an Update Site project and add the features that you want. What kind of problems did you experience?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to manually build an update site is to go through the menu "Export... > Plug-in Development > Deployable features".

In the deployable feature wizard, you can select several features to build.
In the options tab, select the checkbox "Package as individual JAR archives" & "Generate metadata repository".
If you need to categorize your feature in the update site, you can also add a category definition file through this wizard.